# Plot issue and numerical disagreement

Tags: plotting, code-review, code-request

I have to plot this function:

```
Q[ω_] := ArcTan[1/ω]/(1 + 1/2*Log[(1 + ω^2)/ω^2])
```

And I did it through

```
Plot[Q[ω], {ω, 0, 3},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black}]
```

In a very simple way.

The output is the following:

[image]

But here is the problem: the function, as $\omega \to 0$ must be zero.

Why the plot doesn't show that behaviour?

The convergence to zero is really slow (to say: for $\omega \to 10^{-309}$ I just obtained $0.0022$). Is there a way to make the plot to start from zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plot *is* showing this behavior. Change the PlotRange to see it more clearly.

```
Plot[Q[ω], {ω, 0, 3}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.05}, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> {Black}]
```

Better still is to check the limit of the function as ω -> 0

```
In[6]:= Limit[Q[ω], ω -> 0]

Out[6]= 0
```

Comment: Ah, teak you! I suspected it was because of the very slow convergence to zero... Here it is! Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem.  I guess one can do it with appropriate reparametrization and plotting the graph with `PolarPlot`.

Comment: @Artes Actually it did.

Comment: @HenryTuring  The problem was to make an appropriate plot,  when I draw it with `PlotRange -> {{0, 0.05}, Automatic}` values of `Q` start roughly from `0.1`, and when I take `PlotRange -> {{0, 0.001}, Automatic}` I encounter the same issue, i.e. it does not start from `{0, 0}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you plot slightly into the negative then limit the PlotRange to positive values you get this:

```
Plot[Q[ω], {ω, -0.01, 3}
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, Full}}
 , PlotStyle -> {Black}
 , AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}
]
```

[image]

Comment: No need to go negative; `PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Full}}` actually suffices: `Plot[Q[ω], {ω, 0, 3}, AxesStyle -> Opacity[1/2], PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, Full}}, PlotStyle -> {Black}]`

Comment: @J.M. In version 10.1.0 under Windows I do in fact need to, and with your code the line doesn't make it all the way to zero.

Comment: Huh. I guess it's something they did in 11, then...